# Android 11 PDF and Image path issue in ionic application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, android-11

***This is strongly in ionic application.***
I have one image list in which I am showing list of images stored on "Android/data/com.xxxxxx.xxx/files/images/" but in list I am getting below "No image msg" ***in android 11.***

**its working fine in android 10 and below version.**
[image]

Also when i select PDF , its also not coming.
can anyone help me how to select external files in android 11?

***Note:-*** after using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE its working fine, but play storage is rejecting my application.
so any solution other than MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will be good. (***Strongly for Ionic 3*** )
below is my path and error :
*file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.xxxx/files/Certificates/1637134399398/12627383838.pdf* ***net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED***
*file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.xxxx/cache/images/19857828.png*
***net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED***

Comment: Hi. Please, check this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files - Google Play notice section. I think you can try Storage Access Framework (SAF).

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko thanks , but that is purely for android native application. i have developed application in IONIC3

Comment: Yes, but you can change the plugin to access files. IONIC3 uses a plugin to access files - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file . Or you can track this issue - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/426

Comment: Did you have any progress in this?